# How to animate a Function in Matplotlib

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import animation


#make the figure
# - set up figure, set up axis(xlim,ylim), set up line as tuple for 
animation
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(xlim=(-10,50), ylim=(1,50))
line, = ax.plot([],[], lw=2)

#initialization function - display bkgd for each frame
#line has function set data, return it as a tuple
def init():
    line.set_data([],[])
    return line,

speed = 0.01

#animation function - this is where the physics goes
def animate(i): #i is animation frames
    x = np.linspace(0,2,100) #creates set of num evenly spaces from 0,2
    y = (x - speed * i)+(((x - speed * i)^2)/2)+(((x - speed * i)^3)/6)
    line.set_data(x,y)
    return line,

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init,frames=100, 
interval=20, blit=True)

plt.show()
```

I'm trying to approximate "e^x" using the infinite series definition and plot it on a graph.

For whatever reason this code produces a dialog box with a plot for a fraction of a second then ends with an exit code of 1.

I am confused as to why this does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo when you calculate `y`. The exponentiation operator in Python is `**`, not `^`. The code in the original question runs without error if you use `y = (x - speed * i)+(((x - speed * i) ** 2)/2)+(((x - speed * i) ** 3)/6)`.

---

The weird thing is that you don't get the expected traceback. If you try, for example,

```
x = np.ones(5)
x ^ 1
```

you'll get a `TypeError`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/joshk/GitHubProjects/stackoverflow/b.py", line 5, in <module>
    x ^ 1
TypeError: ufunc 'bitwise_xor' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

<strike>It seems like this traceback gets suppressed inside the `FuncAnimator`. I skimmed the [source code](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/animation.py) but nothing jumped out at me as causing the suppression.</strike>

Further investigation indicates that the suppression of the traceback might be caused by PyCharm, not matplotlib.

Comment: When running the original code, I do get exactly the `TypeError: ufunc 'bitwise_xor' not supported for the input types` error repeatedly for each step. So I don't think the traceback is suppressed anywhere in the matplotlib code. Might be that it is suppressed by the program used to run the code though. Nice answer anyways.

Comment: Interesting! I see the traceback when running from the command line, but not from PyCharm - must be a PyCharm problem.